# Exercise 3.12 of Brezis: An Inequality involving Convex Conjugate

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, convex-analysis

This is Exercise 3.12 from Brezis:

> Let $E$ be a Banach space and let $x_0 \in E$. Let $\varphi: E \to (-\infty, +\infty]$ be a convex l.s.c. function with $\varphi \not\equiv +\infty$.
>
> 1. Show that the following properties are equivalent:\begin{align*}\text{(A)} & \text{ There exist }R, \,M < +\infty \text{ such that }\varphi(x) \le M \text{ for all }x \in E \text{ with }\|x - x_0\| \le R. \\ \text{(B)}& \text{ }\lim_{f \in E^*, \| f \| \to \infty} \{\varphi^*(f) - \langle f,\,x_0\rangle\} = \infty.\end{align*}
> 2. Assuming (A) or (B) prove that$$\inf_{f \in E^*} \{\varphi^*(f) - \langle f,\,x_0\rangle\} \text{ is achieved.}$$What is the value of this inf?

I am wonder how we should do for part 1, where $(A) \implies (B)$. The book simply gave the hint: notice $(A)$ implies $\varphi^*(f) \geq R \| f \| + (f, x_0) - M$. However, I can not get this inequality from (A). Here is my attempt:

Suppose (A) holds. That is, there is $R, M < \infty$ such that $\varphi(x) \leq M$, for all $x \in E$ with $\| x - x_0 \| \leq R$. Then we have for all $x \in E$ with $\| x - x_0 \| \leq R$ that
\begin{align*}
    \varphi^*(f) - f(x_0) &\geq f(x - x_0) - \varphi(x) \\
    \varphi^*(f) &\geq \| f \| \| x - x_0 \| - \varphi(x) + f(x_0) \\
    \varphi^*(f) &\geq \| f \| \| x - x_0 \| - M + f(x_0). \\
\end{align*}
It seems like the next step is to use the assumption $\| x - x_0 \| \leq R$, but I don't see how to flip the inequality and make it the one that is on the book.

**An Update**: This is what I was able to show and I wonder if the proof makes sense:
Suppose (A) holds. That is, there is $R, M < \infty$ such that $\varphi(x) \leq M$, for all $x \in E$ with $\| x - x_0 \| \leq R$. Then we have for all $x \in E$ with $\| x - x_0 \| \leq R$ that
\begin{align*}
    \varphi^*(f) - f(x_0) &= \sup_{x \in E} (f(x) - \varphi(x)) - f(x_0) \\
    &= \sup_{x \in E} (f(x - x_0) - \varphi(x)) \\
    &\geq \sup_{x \in E: \| x - x_0 \| \leq R} (f(x - x_0) - \varphi(x)) \\
    &= \sup_{x \in E: \| x - x_0 \| \leq R} (f(x - x_0) - M) \\
    &= \sup_{x \in E: \| x - x_0 \| \leq R} (R f\left(\frac{x - x_0}{R}\right) - M) \\
    &= R \sup_{u \in E: \| u \| \leq 1} f(u) - M \\
    &= R \| f \| - M.
\end{align*}